# What does thick blood indicate?

Tags: blood

I today got a cut on my finger and I saw my blood was thick and sticky. It took less than 1 second to dry and clot as I rubbed  it on my finger. Is thick blood bad for your health?

Comment: It's unlikely your blood is an abnormal viscosity or you would be very ill. However, if you live at high altitude it could be thicker than most people's. http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/does-altitude-related-secondary-polycythemia-make-your-blood-thicker?rq=1

Comment: But I live in normal plain areas not in hills and also I am not ill, Can drinking less water make my blood thick.?

Comment: Being dehydrated could make your blood a little thicker, yes, but I doubt it would be enough to even be noticeable. This notion that you have "thick blood" is just wrong. You most likely have perfectly normal blood.